# Strange Qt include dir structure under OSX

Tags: c++, macos, qt, vim

I am experimenting with Qt headers (for using with vim's `clang-complete` plugin).
For that I am trying to compile a simple qt function (NOTE: this is not supposed to work, just trying to compile it).

```
#include <QWidget>
int main(int, char**) {
  QWidget* a;
}
```

I compile with

```
clang try.cpp -o try -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -isystem/Applications/Qt/5.6/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -isystem/Applications/Qt/5.6/clang_64/./mkspecs/macx-clang -isystem/Applications/Qt/5.6/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -isystem/Applications/Qt/5.6/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers
```

and get the error

```
In file included from /Applications/Qt/5.6/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/QWidget:1:
/Applications/Qt/5.6/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qwidget.h:37:10: fatal error: 
  'QtGui/qwindowdefs.h' file not found
#include <QtGui/qwindowdefs.h>
```

This is because the QWidgets header has `#include <QtGui/...>` includes. This is OK for instance in Linux installations because the folders are set in that order. But in OSX, folders have a distinct structure. Headers for each module are inside `Qt<Module>.framework/Headers/...` instead of `Qt<Module>/`

How the hell do I tell the compiler where the includes are, using this folder structure, if the .h's from Qt are apparently wrong for this folder structure?

Comment: DIdnt you try setting the path?

Comment: @SibiCoder path to where? The problem is that it can't find `QtGui/qwindowdefs.h` because it is not structured in that way in the Qt folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by - manatttta, Qmake spec 'macx-clang' does not expose header folders e.g. `<QtCore/*.h>`, as in Unix and Windows configurations, because it uses the Xcode framework architecture: e.g. `<QtCore.framework/*.h>`.

You can create an alias (symlink) mapping QtCore.framework/headers to QtCore. Be sure to delete any existing Qt-generated Makefile(s) so subsequent build will generate with appropriate include paths.
Here are some example steps to configure:

```
cd <MyApp>/include

mkdir -p MacOSX/Qt/headers

cd MacOSX/Qt/headers

QT_CORE_HEADERS=<your Qt path up to verson subdirectory>/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/Headers

ln -s  $QT_CORE_HEADERS QtCore

Delete existing Makefile `rm -f <MyApp>/Build/Makefile`
```